# Ranking in MySQL using the WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql

My database table gainfinal consists of three columns; countrycode, year and values. I want to rank the countrycode according to the values selecting all the values for year = 2000. 
The Query is like this :

```
SELECT `countrycode` ,  `values` , 
@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM  `gainfinal` , SELECT @curRank := 0) r
WHERE  `year` =  '2000'
ORDER By `values`
```

It says : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @curRank := 0) r WHERE `year` = '2000' ORDER By `values` LIMIT 0 , 30' at line 3. 
Would you please help me.

Comment: Aren't you missing a parenthesis here: `(SELECT @curRank := 0)`?

Comment: As the error says, you have a syntax error: you've got a closing `)` but no opening `(`

Comment: On the plus side, it makes the query look happy `:= 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need extra parentheses:

```
SELECT countrycode, `values`, 
       @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM  gainfinal CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT @curRank := 0) vars
WHERE  year = 2000
ORDER By `values`;
```

You should avoid commas in the `from` clause.  So this uses `cross join` instead.

Also.  You only need to escape identifiers that have unusual characters (such as spaces) or are reserved words (such as `values`).  My advice is to avoid such identifiers.  So, I would suggest that you change the name of `values` to something safer.

Also, you should only use single quotes for string and date constants.  I presume that `year` is numeric, so I removed the single quotes.

Comment: Apart from readability, is there a reason for your recommendation of `CROSS JOIN` over comma in a case like this?

Comment: I'm also curious about what @IMSoP is asking, I always knew that comma separated select was automatically translated to cross joins and never read something against them.

Comment: Commas have two problems in the `from` clause.  First, they suggest that it is ok to have the join conditions in the `where` clause.  (I admit this might be a bit of a "religious" issue, but there is wide-spread agreement on the use of modern join syntax.)  Second, they have different precedence rules from `cross join` and you might get unexpected syntax errors.  Simple advice:  don't use commas in the `from` clause.  They are unnecessary and can lead down the path of bad habits and less-maintainable code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's more or less what I thought: in this specific case, it won't actually make any difference, but as a general habit, using `CROSS JOIN` reinforces the habit of always using the newer syntax.